# How to identify which element belongs to which node in XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt

```
 <main>
    <root>
    <SubRoot>
    <type>R</type>
    <mand>N</mand>
    <Section>B</Section>
    </SubRoot>
    <SubRoot>
    <type>P</type>
    <mand>Y</mand>
    <Section>A</Section>
    </SubRoot>
    </root>
</main>
```

I have above XML file on this file How i can identify that type R or any other element belongs to which node,here it's in first SubRoot node.

In a xsl file i am calling a template if section have value as A and this section is in second SubRoot node as below,
Now i want to access the some other value from second SubRoot node inside the when condition.How can i do that?

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="(/main/root/SubRoot[Section = 'A'])">
    //Call some template 
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    //some template
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I need to verify it dynamically on XSL.Because i am not aware at run  time how many nodes will get generated for the XML.
If Section element having value as A then its inside second SubRoot node.On this basis how can i access the value of other element from second SubRoot Node.Please also help to tell me the performance issue with the suggested approach.

Any Idea Suggestion must be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are not testing whether something is in a SubRoot with Section A, but you are testing whether a SubRoot with Section A exists, that's a huge difference.

I guess what you need is something like `parent::SubRoot[Section/text() = 'A']` which will test whether the direct parent tag is a SubRoot that has a Section with text A.

Or maybe something like `ancestor::SubRoot[Section/text() = 'A']` which will test whether any parent, great-parent, and-so-on tag is a SubRoot that has a Section with text A.

Or maybe something like `ancestor-or-self::SubRoot[Section/text() = 'A']` which will test whether the node itself or any parent, great-parent, and-so-on tag is a SubRoot that has a Section with text A.

Comment: will i use the parent::SubRoot[Section/text() = 'A'] or parent will be name of my parent node.when i am using parent node name instead of parent its giving me error "illegal axis name".

Comment: As the error says, before the :: is an axis name and those are defined. parent means the parent node. Read some XSL docu if you want to know more about the topic. :-)

Comment: i replaced the parent node with /main/root at that time i got that error.Could you please provide me some good link for the reference.Thanks in advance